# Need tableview grouped background in UIView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have Tableview as XIB file, in that inspector I set style as grouped. so the BackGround will be in one format (vertical white lines and light blue) behind the cell.
I want to bring in My UIView. How? There is no style component to set it. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to add the UIView as a header to the table?

Comment: No,you do tableview as grouped in IB.i need in my UIView to add as the background color of that tableview .No relations between tableview and  
UIView

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to set background color of your UIView to the same as UITableView has? If so, just write a line of code [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]]; If you want to set your view as a background of yout table, you can set your tableView's background to [UIColor clearColor] and add it as subview to your view.